# What does the filter.lfs.required Git attribute do?

Tags: git, git-lfs

`git lfs install` sets the `filter.lfs.required` attribute to `true`. This attribute isn't documented anywhere. What does it do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ah actually this is a generic Git attribute that for some reason is not listed in [`gitconfig`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) but it is listed in [`gitattributes`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes).

> If a filter must succeed in order to make the stored contents usable, you can declare that the filter is `required`

So I guess it just means it doesn't abort if the filter fails. However, I tested setting it to false and `git clone`ing an LFS-enabled repo still fails even when it's only the LFS filter that fails, so honestly I have no idea what that setting does.

Comment: If the `required` flag is set, Git will quit *earlier* on such failures; if it's not set, Git will still report, via exit status, that it failed. (This is also likely to affect what shows up in the working tree copy of the file, and perhaps even whether there *is* a working tree copy, if it's the smudge filter that fails.)

Comment: I think the `filter.<driver>.required` config is supposed to be a warning sign to the user: Do not turn this off or whatever is in the repository will become unusable! It doesn't affect the actual workings of git.

Answer (score -2):

It is a large file storage attribute.  Allows you to store binary files optimally.

https://git-lfs.github.com/